# Redirect a Specific Page to another Page and Domain

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website script that installed on the server and pointed to several domains. Sometimes I need to redirect a specific page to another site and for now, I use Cloudflare feature to redirect the page but there limit for a free plan user. So, I want to know how to redirect the specific page on a specific domain using .htaccess, PHP, or etc?

For example, I have content `/blabla` on `first.com` and `second.com`, Then I want to redirect a page `first.com/blabla` to `third.com/target` but not on `second.com/blabla`, both of domain have the same IP and content is in the same folder.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?first\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?blabla http://third.com/something [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect in php:

```
<?php header('Location: '. $newURL); ?>
```

Redirect in javascript:

```
<script>window.location.href = "newurlhere";</script>
```